# How to create a file with name of substring before and after particular character

Tags: java, string, file

I have a name of the file, the path looks like this:

`C:\..\SomeFolder\File1.txt.part1`

I need to crate path somewhat like that

`C:\..\SomeFolder\File1.txt`

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` :

```
str.substring(0, str.length() - ".part1".length());
```

Or

```
str.substring(0, str.length() - 6);//6 is the length of the last part
```

---

```
String str = "C:\\..\\SomeFolder\\File1.txt.part1";
System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 6));
```

this will print :

```
C:\..\SomeFolder\File1.txt
```

Comment: What if i have a lot of names, but there's pattern like that: part1, part2, .., partn. How can i solve it that way?

Comment: you can use this in a method which take a String and return the new String, if all your paths end with the same length then this will help, else you can pass the length also, you can provide another example so we can understand more @Rus9Mus9

Comment: use str.substring(0, str.lasIndexOf(".")) if you're sure you want to exclude all chars after the last point (included).

Comment: yes this is good also @Nemesis can i add it to my answer or you can create your own answer?

Comment: There're a lot of parts, that i should to be just one file. I don't know how many parts, till i declare it in a console.

Comment: mmmm, so @Rus9Mus9 if you are sure about the length of that part then you can use my solution else you can use the solution of Nemesis `str.substring(0, str.lasIndexOf("."))` it take all the String until the last point